# Is WiX compatible with Visual C# 2010 Express?

Tags: wix, visual-c#-express-2010

I downloaded and installed WiX but there are no project templates for it in Visual C# 2010 Express. Is WiX compatible with VC#2010? If so, how can I integrate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Microsoft does not allow the Visual Studio Express SKUs to be extended. Thus it is not possible for the WiX toolset to integrate. We would definitely add support for the Express SKUs to the WiX toolset if Microsoft allowed it.

Comment: That's too bad. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

The WiX Toolset integrates with Visual Studio as an extension. The Express versions of Visual Studio do not allow extension nor addins. So, WiX will not integrate with Express versions.

WiX does work with the free, open source [SharpDevelop IDE](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/), though. It is similar to VS Express but welcomes addins and external tools.

Answer (score 0):

Have to add that it does not mean you can not use WiX Toolset but you have to reference the resources to be installed in the WiX .wxs file or in an include file used by the main .wxs. You can build the MSI with the WiX Toolset like this using only two calls in a .cmd file:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WixEdit\wix-3.0.5419.0\candle.exe" -nologo "Main.wxs" -out "Main.wixobj"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WixEdit\wix-3.0.5419.0\light.exe" -nologo "Main.wixobj" -out "Main.msi"

pause
```

How to design the install Wix project XML of Main.wxs is described here: https://wix.codeplex.com/

The VS Express .csproj and .vbproj files contains some info of what your project is referencing and may be useful to include. Not that many things to include for simple .NET apps. Basically the output .exe maybe a .config file and possibly som other .NET .dll resources you have compiled and is using in your project.